# Trying to use gg_lag() but apparently have more than one time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to find lag using `gg_lag` but I keep getting the same error regarding my `tsibble`

```
# A tsibble: 255 x 6 [7D]
# Key:       Demand [163]
    Week Demand Date          Month year  Quarter
   <dbl>  <dbl> <date>        <mth> <chr>   <qtr>
 1     1     48 2018-01-01 2018 Jan 2018  2018 Q1
 2     2    101 2018-01-08 2018 Jan 2018  2018 Q1
 3     3    129 2018-01-15 2018 Jan 2018  2018 Q1
 4     4    113 2018-01-22 2018 Jan 2018  2018 Q1
 5     5    116 2018-01-29 2018 Jan 2018  2018 Q1
 6     6    123 2018-02-05 2018 Feb 2018  2018 Q1
 7     7    137 2018-02-12 2018 Feb 2018  2018 Q1
 8     8    136 2018-02-19 2018 Feb 2018  2018 Q1
 9     9    151 2018-02-26 2018 Feb 2018  2018 Q1
10    10     87 2018-03-05 2018 Mar 2018  2018 Q1
# ... with 245 more rows
```

> Printer_Q %>% gg_lag(Demand, geom='point')

**Error: The data provided to contains more than one time series. Please filter a single time series to use `gg_lag()`**

I tried filtering my data with:

```
Printer_Q <- Demandts %>%
       select(-Week, -year, -Month, -Quarter)
```

...so that I am left with *Demand* and *Date* but it still says I have more than one time series? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `Demand` column should not be a key variable. A key variable is a categorical variable used to distinguish multiple time series in a single `tsibble`. It appears you just have one time series here, so you don't need a key variable.

Comment: I have never assigned a key variable, that is what I'm struggling with. I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

```Printer_Wts <- as_tsibble(PrinterW, index = "Week") %>%  arrange(Week)```

Update* I've solved it, thank you!

Comment: The printed object shows that `Demand` is a key variable. So somehow you have assigned it. In any case, your proposed solution is simply re-creating the tsibble object with no key and using `Week` rather than `Date` as the index.